# Is it a cognitive bias: "if you guess what I think you do, then what I think of you is true"

Tags: bias

- "If you've guessed what I am thinking (that you do / you have done / you will do / you are), then what I'm thinking of you is True"

Is this considered a cognitive-bias ? And if not what is it ?

Without enough knowledge in Psychology, I tend to think it is close to something like "dementia" / "paranoia" / "psychosis"

Any pointers ?

---

EDIT: it could be rephrased as

What about the phenomenon of: believing one's assumption is true, when the interlocutor does guess the assumed assumption

Comment: I'm not really understanding the construct. Maybe an example would help?

Comment: Please bear in mind that a figure of speech should not be taken as a sign of mental illness. Complex tests are involved in determining mental state. If your question is about the appropriateness of a particular behaviour and how to approach doing something about it, then we've an [interpersonal.se] site which might be of interest to you. There is also [workplace.se] for issues regarding professional relationships with colleagues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you’re talking about [confirmation bias](https://lib.taftcollege.edu/c.php?g=861448&p=6298338). This is when someone seeks out — or in this case *interprets* —evidence in a way that “confirms” for them what they already believe to be true. I would avoid ascribing this to pathology (such as dementia or psychosis) as these are clinical terms that refer to specific states or disorders, whereas all humans are subject to confirmation bias; it can certainly be annoying when someone behaves this way but usually it is not pathological. Cognitive biases which act as development or maintenance factors for a disorder are usually referred to as [cognitive distortions](https://www.health.harvard.edu/blog/how-to-recognize-and-tame-your-cognitive-distortions-202205042738).
I would suggest maybe adding an example next time as the scenario you’ve posed is a bit convoluted. Hope this helps!

Comment: I think if I had put examples it would have become too much correlated to the examples. Your answer is inspiring because it is general. And you address my main concern: is it obviously pathological? It's interesting how the confirmation bias can be disguised.